# Deploy solution button does nothing?

Tags: deployment

I have a WSP file in the Solution Management page of Central Administration of Sharepoint 2007.

I enter its deployment page by clicking its name, then click Deploy Solution, choose Now and click OK. But nothing happens. There is no post-back at all.

Also, Site Actions menu is disabled.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are having a javascript error on that page.  Do you see a Javacript error in the browser?  This is typically what prevents post backs and or Site Actions menu functionality.